# Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' Shutdown initiated... Shutdown completed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a brand new spring boot application,
I have the below dependencies.

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
<artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
```

The application starts but it shutsdown with below warning logs.

```
2022-02-25 23:58:10.225  INFO 72504 --- [           main] c.d.c.l.LibrarydemoApplication           : Started LibrarydemoApplication in 1.512 seconds (JVM running for 2.016)
2022-02-25 23:58:10.230  INFO 72504 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-25 23:58:10.232  INFO 72504 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-02-25 23:58:10.236  INFO 72504 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Mysql connectivity is good. below is the config of application props.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/repo
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Please advise how resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The app started and then exited successfully. Looks like you want it to be a webapp and for that you need to start a webserver.
You can do by adding spring-boot-starter-web dependency to your app.It will add spring-boot-starter-tomcat to your app.

In your maven file add this

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can then get rid of spring-boot-starter as it is included with starter-web dependency

Comment: what if spring-boot-starter-web  is already included in pom.xml but still the error persist?

Comment: @HarishKumar there's a HUGE chance one of your entities or repositories have a problem at initiaition . Try to set spring to log at DEBUG level, and search for this error .And check the last rows before it